# Kth subsequence of a string

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

Given a string S and an integer K, we have to find a string T such that if we lexicographical order all the sub-sequences of the string S then T is at the Kth position.

Here is the link to the problem [Link](http://tdpc.contest.atcoder.jp/tasks/tdpc_lexicographical)

I was practicing problems on dynamic programming and I came across this problem. However I was not able to solve it.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Well i cant give you precise algorithm as i see that the description from the link differs from yours. But you can use a variant of Depth-First-Search to complete this task.

1) Make an algorithm that prints on the console all normal sub-strings. Use a Depth-Fist-Search algorithm to pass through the characters. Each iteration of the algorithm should result in a word. Consider that you pass through a graph with loops, for that you'll need to store all already passed characters at each next iteration - using containers.

2) Create a function, that, taking into account the already processed characters of the current depth level, returns the index of the next lexicographical character. Modify your algorithm so it returns the lexicographical sub-strings with certain length.

Note that this function requires additions for the problem from your link. There is a requirement that the order of the characters must be kept. So before you pass the "processed characters" to the next iteration, you'll also need to make all characters, left from the current character, processed.

4) Instead of printing the sub-strings, now store them in a container and increase a counter for each one. If you already processed the same word, you don't increase the counter. When your counter reaches T, you have your word. If the algorithm finishes and the counter isn't equal to T, print "Eel".